# Serializing as javascript object

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc, serialization

I am working on a Spring MVC and I want to insert javascript into the html output for analytics purpose. I am only partially familiar with serialization but I figured it does the job nicely rather than manually constructing a string containing javascript.

Would it be possible to generate something the following snippet? Any pointers would be great!

```
"emd"   :   new   Date('6/6/2014')
```

**Update**:

I need to output a javascript object which has many fields which may be complex. Hence, on the backend I am gathering all the data into java beans with all the information and I plan to use Jackson mapper to convert to string that I can just output through JSP.

Generating the above snippet does not seem straightforward though, not sure if it is even possible. For context, the rest of that javascript looks something like this.

```
 Analytics.items["item_123"] = {

     //ratings and reviews

    "rat"   : a.b,   //the decimal value for the rating

    "rev"   : xxxx,   //integer

    //list of flags that indicate how the product was displayed to the customer

    //add as needed...tracking code will pick up flags as needed when they are available

    "dec"   : ["mbe",   "green",   "recycled"], 


    //delivery messaging

    "delivery"   : {

            "cd"   :  new   Date()   //current date

            "offers"   : [{

                            "type"   :   "abcd" 

                            "emd"   :   new   Date('6/6/2014'),   

                            "weekend"   :   true

                    }

            ]

    },

};
```

Comment: Are you wanting there to be a javascript variable `emd` to be set to the given date in that JSON attribute? So for example something like `<script>emd=new Date('6/6/2014')</script>` would be generated/rendered from the JSP?

Comment: @ArtyMcFly: Yup, that is what I want rendered from JSP. I am writing a helper java class to generate the necessary javascript shown in the question as a string. The JSP will just render that string within script tags.

Answer (score 0):

[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) should do the trick.  It will be built into your browser, unless you're using a *very* old browser, in which case you can use a [polyfill](http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/).

Comment: JSON.stringify is javascript method. I am looking for how I can generate that snippet from java beans. Maybe use custom Jackson mapper? Maybe I wasn't much clear on my question, I have updated it.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I saw that you were using Spring, but didn't make the connection that you wanted the JSON rendered on the back-end.